# How do I switch frame using "place" in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm new to Tkinter and python. I'm following [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter) to see switch frames and it worked. Next, I'm trying to write the code for switch frames inside `Page One`, but I don't have any idea how to do it.

Below is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        width = 1350  # 1280
        height = 720
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
        y = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
        self.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
        self.resizable(False,False)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))         
        button1.pack()
        


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        LeftFrame=tk.Frame(self,relief=RIDGE, bd=2)
        LeftFrame.place(x=0,y=0,width=160,height=720)

        button = tk.Button(LeftFrame, text="Go to the start page",font=("bold"),command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage")) 
        button.grid(row=0)

        buttonBlue = tk.Button(LeftFrame, text="Go to the blue page",bg="blue",fg="white",command=self.blue,activebackground="blue",activeforeground="white")                   
        buttonBlue.grid(row=1)

        buttonRed = tk.Button(LeftFrame, text="Go to the red page",bg="red",fg="white",command=self.red,activebackground="red",activeforeground="white")                  
        buttonRed.grid(row=2)

        buttonYellow = tk.Button(LeftFrame, text="Go to the yellow page",bg="yellow",fg="black",command=self.yellow,activebackground="yellow",activeforeground="black")
        buttonYellow.grid(row=3)

    def blue(self):
        # self.hide_all_frames()
        blueFrame=tk.Frame(self,relief=RIDGE,bd=1 ,bg="blue")
        blueFrame.place(x=160,y=0,width=1190,height=720)

    def red(self):  # Do I need to put self here? It still worked without putting self here
        # self.hide_all_frames()
        redFrame=tk.Frame(self,relief=RIDGE,bd=1 ,bg="red")
        redFrame.place(x=200,y=0,width=1150,height=720)

    def yellow(self):
        # self.hide_all_frames()
        yellowFrame=tk.Frame(self,relief=RIDGE,bd=1 ,bg="yellow")
        yellowFrame.place(x=240,y=0,width=1110,height=720)

    def hide_all_frames(self):
        self.blue.withdraw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

When I switch to Page One, I create a couple of buttons to switch color frames. They all overlap every time I switch between colors like the image below.
[image: overlap frames]

I'm finding a way to switch color frames without overlapping each other. And, when I go back to the Start Page, all color frames should be destroyed/hidden. Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually you are not *switching frame* but *creating new frame* whenever those `Go to the <color> page` buttons are clicked.

Comment: Yeah. Switching frames need functionality, but my knowledge of Tkinter is limit.

Comment: Elaborate more on *"switch color frames without overlapping each other"*.  What do you expect to see actually?

Comment: I make an assumption that I’m on Page One. When I click red button, the frame of red color background (red frame) will show. If I click blue button, the red frame is hidden and the frame of blue background color is shown. The same to yellow frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the frame switching inside `PageOne`, you need to hide the current frame before showing the requested frame. Also it is better to create the three color frames in the `__init__()` and show it in the corresponding function:

```py
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...

        # create the three color frames with initially hidden
        self.blueFrame = tk.Frame(self, relief=RIDGE, bd=1, bg="blue")
        self.redFrame = tk.Frame(self, relief=RIDGE, bd=1, bg="red")
        self.yellowFrame = tk.Frame(self, relief=RIDGE, bd=1, bg="yellow")

    def blue(self):
        self.hide_all_frames()
        self.blueFrame.place(x=160, y=0, width=1190, height=720)

    def red(self):
        self.hide_all_frames()
        self.redFrame.place(x=200, y=0, width=1150, height=720)

    def yellow(self):
        self.hide_all_frames()
        self.yellowFrame.place(x=240, y=0, width=1110, height=720)

    def hide_all_frames(self, event=None):
        self.redFrame.place_forget()
        self.blueFrame.place_forget()
        self.yellowFrame.place_forget()
```

If you want to hide all color frames after switching frames, i.e. `PageOne` -> `MainPage` -> `PageOne`, you can notify the `PageOne` using virtual event when it is raised.  Then `PageOne` hides all the color frames upon receiving such virtual event:

```py
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    ...

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
        # notify the raised frame via virtual event
        frame.event_generate('<<Raised>>') 

...

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...

        self.blueFrame = tk.Frame(self, relief=RIDGE, bd=1, bg="blue")
        self.redFrame = tk.Frame(self, relief=RIDGE, bd=1, bg="red")
        self.yellowFrame = tk.Frame(self, relief=RIDGE, bd=1, bg="yellow")

        self.bind('<<Raised>>', self.hide_all_frames)
```